# How to do "something" like Combobox in android?

Tags: android, list, combobox

I need something like a combobox in access in android like on this [link](https://lh3.ggpht.com/W89eqMvqowxOi0jG4Z_we86NNy3lVzatqRILC6zdmboXkaAP3QRVcdht1ulkf0BvR3Ev).

when I entered a few letters on both boxes, it will showed particular list related the letters. then when i clicked on the button "find" it will showed a result regarding what I have chosen.

how to do this? I have no ideas. I need suggestions regarding on what I want to do. please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: i think it more like editText which all the the list that show will come from my own database.

Comment: check the autocompletetextview then.. it will serve your purpose

Comment: i want to do exactly like on the picture that i post(link)

Comment: you have to create the design by yourself. I just pointed the feature you told

Comment: @riehime23 you are welocme :). If you think the answer was helpful you can accept/upvote it

Comment: I have a question, what is the difference between autocompletetextview and searchView? i already did the search function,however for that function i used editText and listview. and i discovered the coding for the autocompletetextview almost similar like my search function. can i use my search function code to do autocompletetextview?

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget very similar to a combobox.

It's a dropdown menu called Spinner.

Take a look at the official documentation about [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). You will find some examples there.

Add the code below to your layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="1" />
```

`android:spinnerMode="1"`is very important to show your spinner content as a dropdown list.
Take a look at the [android:spinnerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android%3aspinnerMode) doc to check the only two possible values.